# Showing $\tan^{-1}x+\tan^{-1}\frac{1}{x}=\frac{\pi}{2}$

Tags: simplifying-expressions, trigonometry

Anyone know how to force *Mathematica* to return:

$$\tan^{-1}x+\tan^{-1}\frac{1}{x}=\frac{\pi}{2}$$

I've tried this:

```
ArcTan[x] + ArcTan[1/x] // FullSimplify
```

this:

```
Pi/2 - ArcTan[1/x] // FullSimplify
```

and several other methods, but no luck thus far.

Comment: Note that `x` needs be positive

Comment: This doe not solve your problem, but if you plot `ArcTan[x]+ArcTan[1/x]` you see that your expression is valid only for `x>=0`

Comment: `Assuming[x > 0, ArcTan[x] + ArcTan[1/x] // TrigToExp // FullSimplify]`

Comment: These comments are so helpful. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

This might not be elegant (but may be Bob's method is simpler in the comment)

```
 expr = ArcTan[x] + ArcTan[1/x];
 Normal@Assuming[x > 0, Series[expr, {x, 0, 5}]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]